# Using an second Onclick event to call JS

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm using an `Onclick` that opens a URL inside an iframe. 
It works great as an HREF link, but I've decided to change my second URL into JS function instead of typing it in each of my links.

Here is my added JS:

```
function Link() {
  document.getElementById("TestMe").src = "http://www.cnn.com";
}
```

This is my original Cell link that I'm trying to adjust to be used with the top script. I actually need to change the string `.src='http://www.cnn.com'"` into a `Link()` function.

```
<td bgcolor="#a7d331" height="10" align="center" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.com'); document.getElementById('TestMe').src='http://www.cnn.com'"><font face="Arial" color="FFFFFF" size="4" alt="English">Some Link</font></td>
```

Here is my iframe:

```
<iframe id="TestMe" src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Dude, sorry, I accidentally edited something the same time as you, and then tried to roll back my edit and overwrite you again. My bad man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the assignment with the function call.

```
onclick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.com'); Link();"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that I've missed something. Here is my Cell string after following you line:

<td bgcolor="#a7d331" height="10" align="center" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.com'); link();"><font face="Arial" color="FFFFFF" size="4" alt="English">Click Me</font></td>

Comment: It should be `Link()` not `link()`. Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! I've just missed that. Now it works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function link()
        {
            window.open('http://www.yahoo.com'); 
            document.getElementById('My_Test').src='http://www.cnn.com'
        }
</script>
<td onclick="link()"><font>Some Link</font></td>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I need just the second URL to use the Link() function. The first one should left as URL.

Comment: you can use a flag in link function，such as
function link()
        {
    if(!link.flag)
{
            window.open('http://www.yahoo.com'); 
            link.flag = true;
}
            document.getElementById('My_Test').src='http://www.cnn.com'
        }
link.flag = false;

Answer (score 0):

You can use short-hand `this` which is the DOMElement

```
 onclick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.com'); this.href='http://www.cnn.com';"
```

Keep in mind this will not re arm the link to yahoo.com once the link is clicked twice.

Answer (score 0):

The `td` tag needs to be inside a table in order to be valid HTML; You either need to wrap your cell in a `<table>` element, or change it to a different element (such as a span).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Link() {
   document.getElementById("TestMe").src = "http://www.cnn.com";
}
</script>

<table>
<td bgcolor="#a7d331" height="10" align="center" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.com'); Link();"><font face="Arial" color="FFFFFF" size="4" alt="English">Some Link</font></td>
</table>

<iframe id="TestMe" src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>
```

Comment: What sort of environment are you testing this from (browser, OS)?

Comment: @ Tylet Thanks,  I do have a <table> tag opened. I've just missed the L which should be a case-sensitive. Barmar have noticed my mistake.